# Django Forms: How to iterate over a Choices of a field in Django form

Tags: django, django-forms, django-templates

I dont know if I am doing this in the right manner.

I have a form:

```
class ConnectSelectMultipleForm(forms.Form):
    class Meta:
        model = Connect

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        messages = kwargs.pop('messages')
        choices = []
        if messages:
            pass
        else:
            messages = []

        for message in messages:
            index = (message.id, {message.sender, message, message.id})
            choices.append(index)

        super(ConnectSelectMultipleForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['message'] = forms.MultipleChoiceField(choices=choices,
                                     widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple)
```

As can be seen above i am sending `{message.sender, message ,message.id}` to the template. Now i want to access these variables in the template.

```
{% for field in select_form %}       
    {% for fi in field %}
        {{ fi.message }}
        {{ fi.message.sender }}
        {{ fi.message.id }}
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

The above code is wrong. But can we do something similar to this? Or is there an alternative method to do what i am trying to do?

Thanks in advance.

###Edit

The ouput i am getting by just printing the field is as follows

```
 set([5, u'Everycrave', <Connect: The deal you refered has been bought>])
```

What i want is

Id : 5   ,Name : Everycrave , Content : The deal you refered has been bought

So I want those fields individually

Comment: You haven't explained what you actually want to achieve. What is the output supposed to be, and why can't you just output the field itself?

Comment: The out put that i am getting at present is  set([5, u'Everycrave', <Connect: The deal you refered has been bought>]).Th output i would like is 5 , Everycrave,  The deal you refered has been bought

Comment: But I don't understand what this has to do with the field. A field is for entering/choosing data. What are you trying to enter or choose here?

Comment: self.fields['message'] = forms.MultipleChoiceField(choices=choices,
                                     widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple)


@Daniel sorry for the confusion
The above is a message object which i am giving as a choice field. The user will select it as a multiple choice form. I want to display  all the information of every individual message. Seeing the message , the user can select and delete the individual messages.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't want to "iterate over the field" at all. Django does this for you. The only issue you have is how to create the display value for the field's choices - for some reason, you're creating them as sets, when you just want a string. Your `__init__` method should be something like this:

```
def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    messages = kwargs.pop('messages', None)
    super(ConnectSelectMultipleForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    if messages is None:
        messages = []

    choices = [(message.id, "%s: %s (%s)" % message.sender, message.text, message.id)
               for message in messages]

    self.fields['message'].choices = choices
```

Now you simply refer to the field in the template in the normal way: `{{ form.message }}`.