# How to render individual radio button choices in Django?

Tags: django, django-templates

If I have a model that contains a ChoiceField with a RadioSelect widget, how can I render the radio buttons separately in a template?

Let's say I'm building a web app that allows new employees at a company to choose what kind of computer they want on their desktop.  This is the relevant model:

```
class ComputerOrder(forms.Form):
    name = forms.CharField(max_length=50)
    office_address = forms.Charfield(max_length=75)
    pc_type = forms.ChoiceField(widget=RadioSelect(), choices=[(1, 'Mac'), (2, 'PC')])
```

On the template, how do I render *just* the Mac choice button?  If I do this, it renders all the choices:

```
{{ form.pc_type  }}
```

Somewhat naively I tried this, but it produced no output:

```
{{ form.pc_type.0 }}
```

(I found a few similar questions here on SO:

[In a Django form, how do I render a radio button so that the choices are separated on the page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6766994/in-a-django-form-how-do-i-render-a-radio-button-so-that-the-choices-are-separat)
[Django Forms: How to iterate over a Choices of a field in Django form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7978107/django-forms-how-to-iterate-over-a-choices-of-a-field-in-django-form)

But I didn't feel like they had good answers.  Is there a way to resurrect old questions?)

Comment: Thanks for asking

Answer (score 55, accepted):

Django 1.4+ [allows you to iterate](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/forms/widgets/#radioselect) over the choices in a `RadioSelect`, along with the lines of

```html
{% for choice in form.pc_type %}
  {{ choice.choice_label }}
  <span class="radio">{{ choice.tag }}</span>
{% endfor %}
```

I'm not sure if this change allows you to use the syntax you describe (`{{ form.pc_type.0 }}`) — if not, you could work around this limitation with the `for` loop above and a tag like `{% if forloop.counter0 == 0 %}`.

If you're tied to Django < 1.4, you can either override the `render()` method as suggested or go with the slightly-more-verbose-but-less-complicated option of building up the form field yourself in the template:

```html
 {% for choice in form.pc_type.field.choices %}
   <input name='{{ form.pc_type.name }}' 
     id='{{ form.pc_type.auto_id }}_{{ forloop.counter0 }}' type='radio' value='{{ choice.0 }}'
     {% if not form.is_bound %}{% ifequal form.pc_type.field.initial choice.0 %} checked='checked' {% endifequal %}
   {% else %}{% ifequal form.pc_type.data choice.0 %} checked='checked' {% endifequal %}{% endif %}/>
   <label for='{{ form.pc_type.auto_id }}_{{ forloop.counter0 }}'>{{ choice.1 }}</label>
 {% endfor %}
```

(`choice.0` and `choice.1` are the first and second items in your `choices` two-tuple)

Comment: {{ choice.1 } needs to be {{ choice.1 }}

awesome solution :D

Comment: Thanks for the correction! Remember you can always directly suggest an edit by clicking "edit" under someone's answer :)

Answer (score 6):

The rendering of the individual radio inputs is handled by the `RadioSelect` widget's `render` method. If you want a different rendering, subclass `RadioSelect`, change the `render` method accordingly, and then use your subclass as the field's widget.

Answer (score 4):

I think the simply looking at what's available inside the for loop of a choice field will tell one what they need to know.  For example, I needed the value to set a class surrounding the span of the option (for colors and such):

```
<div>
    {% for radio_input in form.role %}
        {# Skip the empty value #}
        {% if radio_input.choice_value %}
            <span class="user-level {{ radio_input.choice_value }}">{{ radio_input }}</span>
        {% endif %}
    {% endfor %}
</div>
```

There are several attributes as you can see that keep you from having to use the ordinal.

[image: PyCharm Debugging Inside a Template]

Answer (score 3):

In Django 2.0+ you can subclass `forms.RadioSelect` and "simply" specify a template for rendering the radio fields:

```
class SlimRadioSelect(forms.RadioSelect):
    template_name = 'includes/slim_radio.html'
```

where `slim_radio.html` contains a revised version of the combined `template_name` and `option_template_name` used by the [default RadioSelect widget](https://github.com/django/django/blob/stable/3.0.x/django/forms/widgets.py#L757).

Note, the default RadioSelect widget template is low-level rendering and consists of heavily layered templates: include, conditional and loop logic tags abound.

You'll know you've arrived when you're digging around in `packages/django/forms/templates/django/forms/widgets/input.html` to get what you need.

One other oddity for overriding the default widget's template is that you must invoke the [TemplatesSetting](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/forms/renderers/#django.forms.renderers.TemplatesSetting) renderer or your subclass [won't be able to find](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52184422/4028977) `slim_radio.html` in your project's normally accessible template paths.

To override RadioSelect's local-only template path lookup:

1. Add `'django.forms'` to your `INSTALLED_APPS`;
2. Add `FORM_RENDERER = 'django.forms.renderers.TemplatesSetting'` to your `settings.py.`

This all seems harder than it should be, but that's frameworks. Good luck.